# Should/can I do nested receives for TCP data?

Tags: erlang

Can I Nest `receive {tcp, Socket, Bin} ->` calls?  For example I have a top level loop called Loop, which upon receipt of tcp data calls a function, parse_header, to parse header data (an integer which indicates the kind of data to follow and thus its size), after that I need to receive the entire payload before moving on.
  I might only receive 4 bytes when I need a full 20 bytes and would like to call receive in a separate function called parse_payload.  So the call chain would look like `loop->parse_header->parse_payload` and I would like parse_payload to call 
`receive {tcp, Socket, Bin} ->`. 
 I don't know if this ok or if I'm completely going to mess things up and can only do it in the Loop function.  Can someone enlighten me?  If I am allowed to do this is am I violating some sort of best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can check the sample code for "erlang programming".
The download page is [Erlang Programming Source Code](http://pragprog.com/titles/jaerlang/source_code)

In file socket_examples.erl, please check "receive_data" function.

For perse message, I think you should determine how to seperate messages one by one (fixed length or with termination byte), then parse message's header, and payload.

```
receive_data(Socket, SoFar) ->
    receive
    {tcp,Socket,Bin} ->    %% (3)
        receive_data(Socket, [Bin|SoFar]);
    {tcp_closed,Socket} -> %% (4)
        list_to_binary(reverse(SoFar)) %% (5)
    end.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set a gen_tcp socket in passive mode. This way, the owning process won't receive the input by messages but has to fetch it using **gen_tcp:recv(Socket, ByteCount)** which returns either **{ok, Input}** or **{error, Reason}**. As this methods waits infinitely for the bytes you might want to add a timeout using **gen_tcp:recv/3**. ([Erlang documentation of gen_tcp:recv](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#recv-2))

While at first glance it might seem the process is now completely unable to react to messages sent to it, there is the following workaround improving the situation a bit:

```
f1(X) ->
    receive
        message1 ->
            ... do something ...,
            f1(X);
        message2 ->
            ... do something ...,
            f1(X)
        after 0 %timeout in ms
            {ok, Input} = gen_tcp:recv(Socket, ByteCount, Timeout),
            ... do something ... % maybe call some times gen_tcp:recv again
            f1(X)
    end.
```

If you don't add a timeout to gen_tcp:recv here, other processes could wait ages for f1 to handle their messages.